# Sample name generator that randomly picks from an array of names

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a linq random selector that randomly selects from an array of names?

```
 var randomname = {"Jess", "Jay", "Jen", "Jack", "Jan"}.select(a => a.random());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just use a random number generator and sort through it:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var randomname = {"Jess", "Jay", "Jen", "Jack", "Jan"}.OrderBy(a => rnd.NextDouble()).First();
```

Comment: syntax correction, var rnd = new Random();
                var randomName = new[]{ "Jess", "Jay", "Jen", "Jack", "Jan" }.OrderBy(a => rnd.NextDouble()).First();

Answer (score 1):

No need for LINQ here. Just use [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) with an upper and lower bound:

```
string[] items = { "Jess", "Jay", "Jen", "Jack", "Jan" };
Random r = new Random();

int index = r.Next(0, items.Length);
string randomItem = items[index];
```

**Example:** http://dotnetfiddle.net/EiRwGl

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .skip

```
Random rand = new Random();
int toSkip = rand.Next(0, randomname.Count  );
randomname.Skip(toSkip).Take(1).First(); //Or without linq a randomname[toSkipe];
```